IMMUTABLE TOKEN EDIT NAME
Hi I have revoked metadata change, and I see it was wrong, is possible to edit a name from immutable token... I revoked wrong...
IT WAS ONFANS same as ticker and is ONLY FANS how the chance I do a fix?

If we refer to a Solana Immutable Token, it means that the metadata of the token can NOT be changed. once metadata update authority is revoked, there's no way to update it.
